# Need help to "move" some relationships FROM Access TO Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

I have a database of economists in Microsoft Access, and i need to transfer it to Neoj.

Keep in mind that all these economists have also been teachers.

So, I have a table - **Economist** - where i store all economists data, with an ID "*codecon*" for each economist. Then, i have a table - **University** - where i store information about Universities, with an ID "*coduni*" for each University.
As last i have a table - **Subject** - with subjects informations, with an ID "*codsubj*" for each subject.

Now, in Access i have another table - **Teaching**, where i use the previous IDs to say that "Economist *codecon* teach Subject *codsubj* in University *coduni*.

How can i create this type of link in Neo4j, where i can only have relationships between TWO nodes?

Any help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to think about what your graph data model is going to look like. After that, you might want to use a tool to model it. Finally, you'll want to load the data in. You can use LOAD CSV if you've got the data exported out of Access as csv files, APOC has an [XLS importer](http://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/3.5/export-import/load-xls/).

I think you'll find this following starter guide - going from [relational to graph](https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-importing-data-and-etl/) helpful. I would also suggest you start with exporting your tables to begin with to CSV.

For data modelling, I find [arrows](http://www.apcjones.com/arrows/#) helpful.